# Google Sheets - Conditional Formatting - Multiple Check Boxes

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, checkbox, array-formulas, gs-conditional-formatting

[image: Google Sheets Check Boxes Conditional Formating Multiple Boxes.]

I am trying to make conditional formatting in google sheets so that if one box is checked, the row highlights orange; if the second checkbox is marked, the row is highlighted red; and if both checkmarks are marked, the row highlights green. I think I can do this if I create a formula:

```
=IF([$Z4]$1 = 1, "A") + IF([$AA4]$2 = 1, "B") +IF([$z4:$AA4]$3 = 1, "C")
```

and then set the conditional formating based on the letter returned by the formal. Some help would be appreciated

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 0):

try in `AB4` cell

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B4:B="",,
 IF((Z4:Z *1 = 1)*(AA4:AA *1 = 0), "A",  
 IF((Z4:Z *1 = 0)*(AA4:AA *1 = 1), "B", 
 IF((Z4:Z *1 = 1)*(AA4:AA *1 = 1), "C", )))
```

Comment: Player0 Thank you for answering the question. Your formula seemed to work; however, when I try to add a new row for a new job, the method appears not to carry over.

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?